# In an ideal gas, is the pressure dependent on the mass of the molecules?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

If you take the ideal gas law and substitute $\dfrac mM$, where $m$ is mass of the particles and $M$ is molecular weight, you can derive $D = \dfrac{MP}{RT}$ with algebraic manipulation, where $D$ is density.

From this, I initially thought that pressure was dependent on mass since mass and pressure are both on numerator of opposite sides. But then, I realized that volume is proportional to mass, so essentially it would cancel out the numerator mass, making pressure not dependent on pressure.

I'm still not $100$% sure about this conclusion. Would appreciate it if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressure, like temperature, is an intensive thermodynamic property. It does not depend on the mass.

Suppose you have a room filled with air (which can typically be considered an ideal gas), at 1 atmosphere pressure and room temperature of 20 C. If you divide the room into two equal parts by a wall, the pressure and temperature in each half will be the same, though the mass of the air in each room is half of that for the entire room.

$\frac{m}{M}$ is simply the number of moles, $n$, of the gas. $D$ is simply $\frac{m}{V}$. So your expression

$$D=\frac{MP}{RT}$$

is simply

$$PV=nRT$$

The ideal gas law where $n$ is the number of moles of gas and $R$ is the universal gas constant.

So pressure is proportional to the number of moles of gas, not the mass of the gas. If you replace a given gas with one with double the molecular weight, for $n$ to be the same, the mass of the replacement gas has to be double the mass. Yet the pressure is the same. Pressure is not dependent on mass.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to consider a condition where the temperature is not a factor, I am assuming isothermal conditions i.e., $T=$ constant.

CASE I: $V=$ constant
$$\frac{m}{P}=\frac{MV}{RT}\Rightarrow P\propto m$$
More the gas stuffed inside the container, the more the pressure.

CASE II: $P=$ constant.
$$\frac{m}{V}=\frac{MP}{RT}\Rightarrow V\propto m$$
More the gas, the more the volume required to accommodate it.